Trajectory of Launch
Where online are the anticipated  trajectory of rocket launches shown prior to launches from Florida?  This will allow ability to find launches in flight.

related: How can I find sources for Launch Trajectories? and How far south can one see a rocket launch from Cape Canaveral, Florida? and How to determine rocket launch path for photography? and What should I consider in choosing what launch to see live? and Resources for planning and schedule a launch-watching day-trip in Florida?...

...and How can I know which direction a launch will be?
